# Little gear inside sink's faucet: what is it and what does it do?

Tags: water, faucet, sink, replacement, water-damage

This little gear fell out of our faucet (the house is ~ 11 years old). It's about 1cm (0.4 inch) in diameter and 0.5 cm (0.2 inch) in height. The other faucet in the same bathroom seems to have same gear inside, near the opening where water comes out.

[image]

What is the thing called and what does it do? Can I buy replacement for just the thing and stick it back inside the faucet?

Answer (score 2):

It appears to be one variant of an **aerator** - you can either stick it back in or get one to replace it. In some cases the function is both aeration and limiting maximum flow rate.

An aerator introduces small bubbles into the water stream which causes it to splash less than an un-aerated stream - they are abundantly common (nearly all faucets have them - very few do not.)